# In iOS, is it a good pratice to build an generic UI Component using UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I want to build a generic UI Component (one that will handle its own view and logic, data source, 
etc), is it a good practice to subclass UIViewController?

Comment: What are the responsibilities of this component? I suspect that in most cases all you really want is a UIView subclass and possibly some delegate or data source protocols for it. In some cases you might have behavior which requires a controller but I would consider that a warning sign that your component is larger and more complex than really necessary. Impossible to say for sure without knowing what you think this component should do.

Comment: Well suppose I have a view and I want to added widgets to it as subviews. Each widget should display very different kind of data, maybe completely unrelated. If I just subclass UIViews for these widgets, where should the delegate and data source go to? If they're all go to the parent UIViewController, the code will be really messy.

Comment: You can just as easily set a `UIView` subclass, rather than a `UIViewController` subclass, as a delegate of another `UIView`....

Comment: Right but isn't it a bad practice to use UIView as delegate/data source? I've been told that UIView should only know to how to render things.

Comment: @Duc it seems like you have an additional "how do I avoid creating massive view controller classes" question which is a slightly different problem. I think what you are looking for is to be willing to create new classes and objects to fill specific roles. It's fine (and useful) to have a `NSObject` subclass which just maps your data model to some view's data source protocol. Then your controller only have to create an instance of that class and pass it to the view, not implement the protocol itself.

Comment: @Duc Another way to address your controller complexity concern might be to try to imagine what your controllers would look like if all they did was setup their views and pass data to the view for display or from the views to some other component to act on.

View controllers don't need to know how to save or retrieve data, create some service that does only that and pass an instance of the service to the view controller.

Answer (score 2):

I would say no. But it depends. If your component manages other view controllers or has/will have any kind of logic that's not specific to a view (e.g. navigation logic, business logic etc) , then you should subclass a view controller. *Then again that makes it more than an UI component.*

Otherwise, you should subclass an UIView, like Apple does with many components, including UITableView (speaking of datasource), GLKView, UICollectionView.

Comment: (Repost from my above comment). If I just subclass UIViews, how do I deal with the case where I want many different kinds of UI Components (which may be unrelated) to be shown in a single screen. Would my ViewController be overloaded with datasource and delegate code for those different kind of UI Components?

Comment: @Duc In most cases, every user interface component is a `UIView` subclass and they are all managed by a `UIViewController`. Your view controller would probably implement any necessary delegate and data source methods. It shouldn't be too hard to keep track of if you organize and document your methods well. If each component is very complex, you could split the duties between multiple controllers and use a container controller like a UISplitViewController to display them. If it's messy, organize it. I haven't had much of a problem keeping track of long controller code.

Comment: I don't think `overloaded` is the right word. It's good to have access to all ui components in the view controller that manages them. If you're worried about the amount of code you'll have in your view controller you can use categories to divide it in several files (in a logical manner).

Answer (score 2):

My overly simplistic answer is "no, when building a generic component do not automatically start with a `UIViewController` subclass". However that alone is not a useful answer and in some cases a `UIViewController` subclass is exactly the right solution.

Instead let's consider how to decide what your component should be. I think the best way to figure that out is to answer three questions:

1. What is this component responsible for?
2. How do you want to interact with it?
3. What are its dependencies?

In all cases we can try to start as simple as possible and add complexity only when the answers to those questions require it.

Could this component just be a function? No objects, no classes, if all you want to add is some behavior then maybe all we need is a function. If this behavior only applies to specific existing types then maybe we need a category on an existing class.

Not enough to cover what we want to do? Ok, I guess we might be talking about a new type so let's create a class. Can it just be a subclass of `NSObject`?

Want to display something in a view? Ok, then we at least have a `UIView` subclass, maybe a `UIControl` subclass if it is more interactive.

The view needs some data to back it? No problem sounds like we now need two pieces; a view to display data and a data source to provide it. Here the view shouldn't need to know who creates and owns this data source. As long as one was provided to the view we can use it, anything else is outside of the view's area of responsibility. Similarly we might add a delegate to notify some other object of interactions with the view.

If we still haven't covered all of this component's responsibilities then maybe we need yet another piece, something in the controller layer to manage our view. We're still not (yet) talking about a `UIViewController` though! It's fine to have a "controller" or "service" that is a `NSObject` subclass. If all this piece needs to do is manage network connections, or map `NSFetchedResultController` results to our view's data source protocol and update the view, or just provide a convenient implementation of the most common mapping of model objects to the view's data source then a simple "controller" object is still all we need.

Still not enough? Finally we get to the point where we consider providing a `UIViewController` subclass. Maybe we want to allow users of the component to just present a modal view controller to hand off responsibility for an interaction (send an email, compose a tweet). Maybe there's a common set of default behaviors we want to provide that are tied to view controller life cycle events (`UITableViewController` flashing scroll bars in `-viewDidAppear:`).

Build your component from the pieces you need to support the behaviors you want to provide but keep it as small and simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's good practice in many cases.  The iOS SDK contain many examples of `UIViewController` subclasses.  A few of them contain only a small amount of generic behavior and are essentially useless without customization:

- `GLKViewController`
- `UICollectionViewController`
- `UITableViewController`

And some of them provide significant generic behavior but are still mainly containers for your own view controllers:

- `UINavigationController`
- `UIPageViewController`
- `UISplitViewController`
- `UITabBarController`

But most of them are essentially complete packages with little or no need (or ability) to customize their behavior:

- `ABNewPersonViewController`
- `ABPersonViewController`
- `ABUnknownPersonViewController`
- `EKCalendarChooser`
- `EKEventEditViewController`
- `EKEventViewController`
- `GKAchievementViewController`
- `GKFriendRequestComposeViewController`
- `GKGameCenterViewController`
- `GKLeaderboardViewController`
- `GKMatchmakerViewController`
- `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController`
- `MFMailComposeViewController`
- `MFMessageComposeViewController`
- `MPMediaPickerController`
- `MPMoviePlayerViewController`
- `PKAddPassesViewController`
- `QLPreviewController`
- `SKStoreProductViewController`
- `SLComposeViewController`
- `TWTweetComposeViewController`
- `UIActivityViewController`
- `UIImagePickerController`
- `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`
- `UIVideoEditorController`

If you think about what all of these have in common, you may conclude that they all have two things in common:

- Each has a specific model (in the MVC sense) that it interacts with, and that model is not specific to your app.  The models vary widely (`UIVideoEditorController`'s model is a single video; `UIImagePickerController`'s model is the entire photo library; `GKAchievementViewController`'s model is a database possibly on an Apple server in “the cloud”), in some cases you provide the model (or some properties of the model) up front, and in some cases you receive the model (or a fragment of it) at the end.  But in every case, the view controller handles all the interaction between the user and the model with little or no ongoing help from your app.
- Each provides its own view hierarchy, with little or no customization required (or even permitted).

In other words, each of these view controllers isn't just the “C” of an MVC pattern.  It's the tip of an entire MVC iceberg.

If your component is also an MVC iceberg, then exposing the tip of your iceberg as a `UIViewController` subclass is quite appropriate.

Comment: What if I want generic UI components that are not single-screen, but can be embed inside another view? Does this still apply?

Comment: Many of the ones I listed can be embedded in other view controllers.

Comment: Note that aside from container view controllers, a lot of these are just generic view controllers that handle a UIView subclass. The interface element itself is not a view controller. For instance, a UITableViewController is not a UITableView, although it manages one.

Comment: I would say that almost none of them are “just generic view controllers that handle a UIView subclass”.  I have revised my answer to clarify that.

Comment: @robmayoff All I meant was that the UIViewController subclasses are not interface components themselves; they just *manage* interface components. I felt the need to point that out just to clear up any possible confusion. I think the edit added some much needed clarity. A great deal of interface components are fine being dealt with directly, because they aren't "icebergs." If you're having trouble dealing directly with the component, I'd prioritize making the component itself easier to use. Of course, sometimes a custom controller is the best solution to mask off complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the iOS version you used.

A. prior to iOS 5.0, It's not a good practice, and not recommend.

B. start with iOS 5.0, It's just ok.

subclass a view controller for a UI component (UIView), , that means you wanna use the view controller life cycle method, to manage the user interaction and view display procedure, data model etc. So, if the life cycle method can not easily automatic called, the view controller is not that meaningful.

start with iOS 5.0, it's possible to create custom view controller container, so, it's ok to build custom generic ui component with view controller to  add as a child view controller.

prior to iOS 5.0. Subclass a UIView with custom delegate protocol is the right way. one other thing is about the code organize.  put the all custom delegate method to another custom class, not in the view controller, in the view controller just init a delegate class instance, and set this to the view delegate property.